# How do I create a variable from an input field and pass it on to the URL of an API call?

Tags: javascript, api

I am trying to design a search bar that creates a variable out of whatever text is inputted into it and then inserts it into the URL of an API call. The variable referred to is `searchString`. It is an empty string originally. The `searchBar` assigns to it a specific value, and now the problem is how to make that value be taken up by the `getArtworks` API call.

This is the code:

```
const baseURL = 'https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks/search?q=';
let searchString = '';

const searchBar = document.getElementById('searchBar');
searchBar.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if(e.key === "Enter"){
    searchString = e.target.value
    console.log(searchString)
    return searchString
  }
});

const getArtworks = async () => {
  const results = await fetch(`${baseURL}${searchString}&size=12&fields=id,title,image_id,artist_title`);
  const artworks = await results.json();
  return artworks;
};

export { getArtworks }
```

I have tested with a console log to make sure that the `searchBar` assigns a value to `searchString`, and it does. I have also changed the original assignment of the variable, at the top of the page, from an empty string to something specific (like "picasso", for example), and it then gives me the expected results (that is, Picasso artworks). The problem is that I cannot make the variable bridge `searchBar` and `getArtworks`.

Here is the relevant portion of the `displayArtworks` function, the part which calls the `getArtworks` function, in case it is needed to make the workings of the app more clear.

```
const displayArtworks = async () => { 
  const objCollection = await getArtworks();
  const arrCollection = objCollection.data;
  const artworksList = document.getElementById('artworks-list');
  arrCollection.forEach((artwork) => {
...
  });
};
```

Thanks in advance to anyone that can lend me a hand.

Comment: How are you verifying that this is _not_ working? When and where are you calling `getArtworks()`?

Comment: @Phil What I provided is just the page of my webpack project where I do the API calls. There is an Html index page as well as a Js page for displaying the artworks fetched from the API. Didn't think they were relevant to include in the description.

Comment: @Yogi Thanks for providing that option. The matter here is that my app is strung together with webpack and I have to do calls to the API from several different pages.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood my two questions. 1) **How are you verifying that this is _not_ working?** Are you seeing the request made in your dev-tools _Network_ panel? Does it have the expected query params or not? 2) **When and where** are you calling `getArtworks()`? What triggers that function to execute?

Comment: @Phil I verify that this is not working because when I initialize `searchString`  with some specific value at the top of the page the api is fetching the data and it is displayed. So the problem lies with the addEventListener arrrow function not passing out the value to  `getArtworks()`.`getArtworks()` is being called from `displayArtworks()` immediately as the content is loaded. I have updated the statement of my inquiry so that it includes 
 `displayArtworks()` to make things more clear.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `URL Constructor` to build out the address that you pass to your fetch function.

[URL: searchParams property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams)

> ```
> let params = new URL(document.location).searchParams;
> let name = params.get("name"); // is the string "Jonathan Smith".
> let age = parseInt(params.get("age")); // is the number 18
> ```